# Macbook Pro Retina Water Spill

Tags: macos, laptop, power-supply, macbook, battery

I have a Macbook Pro Retina (early 2015) that had some water spilled on it. Initially, it wouldn't power on at all. After leaving it for some time to dry it eventually booted up.

However, when connected to the power adapter, the light on the charger goes from green to orange as expected. After leaving the charger connected for a few hours it appears the battery isn't actually charging because if I remove the cord the computer immediately shuts off and resets the clock.

The macOS system preferences, shows the battery as "replace now", "not charging", and that it has 348 cycles. It also indicates that the battery currently has ~4,000 mAh (seeming to indicate it can actually hold a charge).

I am asking this question despite the fact that there are many identical questions online, but none address the exact situation.

Is there any particular part I should investigate or operation to perform that might be the issue. I have tried the reset PRAM and also verified the disk permissions for good measure.

I am comfortable working on the innards, but don't know what specific part to start with.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, if you want to rescue the data on the disk then remove the disk and try it in a known working system. If is is about restoring the whole laptop: disconnect as many parts as possible and see if it work. If it does and fails on connecting one item then that item is broken. If it still fails then considerproblems with the motherboard. Also, which water was spilled on ot, destilled (clean) water or tap water?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to rescue the data (it's a PCI SSD so I doubt it would be removable anyway), but it was working fine before the spill (tap water). I doubt that the software would have been affected by a water spill.

Comment: PCi SSD or PCI-e SSD? If the latter look for an M.2 disk (which takes one screw to remove).   Though I know MAscs also used NVME disk with a custom 22 pins connector and there are convertors from that from custom22 pins to M.2

Comment: Sounds like the charging/power switching system is dead. If it powers up the connector itself is ok. The power delivery is part of the main "logic board" as apple call it so the steps I would take would be A. a thorough clean with Iso Alcohol and failing that B. Replace the board. IC replacement on said is a difficult job that you cannot do without a fully equipped repair lab.